# Camera opens with grey color on window7 using cvCaptureFromCAM function in VS 2013

Tags: qt, opencv, camera

My camera opens grey in color,Why does this happen?
Heres the capture function part of code..

```
 #include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
using namespace std;
 using namespace cv;
 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) : QMainWindow(parent), ui(new  Ui::MainWindow)
   {
  //An Array of the pattern alphabets
stopCapture = true;
alphabetTable[0]="A.jpg";
alphabetTable[1]="B.jpg";
alphabetTable[2]="C.jpg";
alphabetTable[3]="D.jpg";
alphabetTable[4]="E.jpg";
alphabetTable[5]="F.jpg";
color = cvScalar(0x00, 0x00, 0xff);
showGray = false;
startmatching = false;
timer1 = new QTimer(this);
connect(timer1, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(stopped_timer()));
ui->setupUi(this);
```

}

```
  //Start the capture function
```

void MainWindow::Capture(){

```
float matchresult = 1;
p_capWebcam = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
cvNamedWindow("Original", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
if (p_capWebcam != NULL)
{
    while (true)
    {
        IplImage *frame = cvQueryFrame(p_capWebcam);
        cvShowImage("WEBCAM_TEST", frame);
        cvWaitKey(20);
    }
}
else
{
    std::cout << "CAMERA NOT DETECTED" << std::endl;
}

IplImage * tableauxImage[6];

for (int i = 0; i<6; i++)
{
    tableauxImage[i] = cvLoadImage(alphabetTable[i], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
}

while (1){

    p_imgOriginal = cvQueryFrame(p_capWebcam);
    p_gray = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(p_imgOriginal), 8, 1);
    cvFlip(p_imgOriginal, p_imgOriginal, 1);
    cvCvtColor(p_imgOriginal, p_gray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    cvSetImageROI(p_gray, cvRect(100, 100, 200, 200));
    cvThreshold(p_gray, p_gray, 100, 255, CV_THRESH_BINARY_INV);
    MainWindow::draw_box(p_imgOriginal, cvRect(100, 100, 200, 200));

    // when show Roi Button is clicked
    if (showGray == true) {
        cvNamedWindow("template gray", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
        cvShowImage("template gray", p_gray);
    }

    cvShowImage("Original", p_imgOriginal);
    for (int i = 0; i<6; i++){
        if (startmatching == true)
            matchresult = MainWindow::match_two_shapes(tableauxImage[i], p_gray);

        if (matchresult<0.1){
            ui->signname->setText(QString(convertstring(alphabetTable[i])[0])); //good match
            timer1->start(1000);
        }

        else {
            if (matchresult<0.25)
                color = cvScalar(0x00, 0xff, 0x00);
            else
                color = cvScalar(0x00, 0x00, 0xff);
        }
        ui->matchresultlabel->setText(QString::number(matchresult));
    }
    charCheckForEscKey = cvWaitKey(ui->Delais->value());// delay (in ms), and get key press, if any
    if ((charCheckForEscKey == 27) || (stopCapture))
        break;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
{
    cvReleaseImage(&tableauxImage[i]);
}
cvReleaseCapture(&p_capWebcam);
cvDestroyAllWindows();
```

}

I am using Windows 7 OS with my inbuilt lenovo camera
A simple opencv program to open camera works fine..and also  using VS2013 with opencv 3.3.0 and qtcreator for gui
How can my camera open to capture images ...What is wrong with the code??
Please help..!!

Comment: Just an advice - don't use `IplIamge` but instead use `cv::Mat`. Now to your question - is it possible that your webcam has some setting turned on thus altering the image that the driver delivers when capturing data and sending it to your application? I'm assuming that you are talking about how `p_imgOriginal` looks.

Comment: can u convert iplimage to cv::Mat n show the code...coz im getting errors